# JSON Schema - only allow existing keys as value in another object

Tags: json, jsonschema

Suppose I have the following JSON object:

```
{
    "firstKey": {
        "innerKey": null
    },
    "secondKey": {
        "innerKey": null
    },
    "thirdKey": {
        "innerKey": "firstKey"
    }
}
```

By using JSON-Schema, how do I make sure that `innerKey` can only be `firstKey` or `secondKey`, or `null` (i.e. how do I only allow existing keys from an other object as a value)?

Comment: This is not possible with the current versions of JSON schema. You would need to check in a separate validation step.

Comment: It is not probably what you want to achieve, but you may define an enum, so innerKey can only be one of  ["firsKey", "secondKey", null]. But this enum should be built by specifying the keys.

Answer (score 0):

As @Clemens told there this is not possible generally. But if you have JSON input with `limited` number of `well defined` properties you could try something like this.

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "firstKey": {
      "properties": {
        "innerKey": {
          "allOf": [
            {
              "$ref": "#/definitions/innerKey"
            },
            {
              "not": {
                "const": "firstKey"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    "secondKey": {
      "properties": {
        "innerKey": {
          "allOf": [
            {
              "$ref": "#/definitions/innerKey"
            },
            {
              "not": {
                "const": "secondKey"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    "thirdKey": {
      "properties": {
        "innerKey": {
          "allOf": [
            {
              "$ref": "#/definitions/innerKey"
            },
            {
              "not": {
                "const": "thirdKey"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "definitions": {
    "innerKey": {
      "oneOf": [
        {
          "enum": [
            "firstKey",
            "secondKey",
            "thirdKey"
          ]
        },
        {
          "type": "null"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```